# block the next element of an accordion and only show when the inputs are filled

Tags: javascript, html

I have this accordion with three steps, in the first step I ask for the first and last name.

How could I make steps 2 and 3 blocked until the user fills in the fields in step 1?

```
<style>
output {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 0fr;
        transition: grid-template-rows 0.125s;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    div {
        min-height: 0;
    }

    .ocultar_check{
        display: none;
    }

    [type="radio"]:checked+output {
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    }

    fieldset {
        border: 0;
        display: grid;
        gap: 0.2rem;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-inline: auto;
        padding: 1rem;
    }

    .pasos {
        padding: 0.5rem;
        color: #1E1E1E;
        font-weight: 600;
        background: #dddddd;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background 0.125s;
        border-radius: 0.2rem;

        &:hover {
            background: oklch(0.8 0 0.1);
        }
    }
</style>

<fieldset id="accordion">
        <label for="1" class="pasos">Step1</label>
        <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="1" value="1" checked>
        <output>
            <div>                  
                  <input placeholder="name" class="field__input" id="name" name="" required/>                                   
                  <input placeholder="last name" class="field__input" id="last name" name="" required/>
            </div>
        </output>
        <label for="2" class="pasos">Step2</label>
        <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="2" value="2">
        <output>
            <div>
                <input placeholder="phone" class="field__input" id="phone" name="" required/>         
            </div>
        </output>
        <label for="3" class="pasos">Step 3</label>
        <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="3" value="3">
        <output>
            <div>
                <input placeholder="address" class="field__input" id="address" name="" required/>          
            </div>
        </output>
</fieldset>
```

For example, I fill in the fields in step 1 and if they are filled, I can just access step 2 and so on. If step 1 is not filled out, I can't access the next steps. I'm new to js, ​​any help is appreciated THANKS

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code in js

```js
const step1NextBtn = document.getElementById('step1Next');
    const step2NextBtn = document.getElementById('step2Next');
    const step3NextBtn = document.getElementById('step3Next');

    const nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
    const lastNameInput = document.getElementById('last_name');
    const phoneInput = document.getElementById('phone');
    const addressInput = document.getElementById('address');

    step1NextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (nameInput.value.trim() !== '' && lastNameInput.value.trim() !== '') {
            document.getElementById('2').checked = true;
        }
    });

    step2NextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (phoneInput.value.trim() !== '') {
            document.getElementById('3').checked = true;
        }
    });

    step3NextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (addressInput.value.trim() !== '') {
            // You can optionally add code here to handle form submission
        }
    });
```

```html
<fieldset id="accordion">
    <label for="1" class="pasos">Step 1</label>
    <input class="hide_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="1" value="1" checked>
    <output>
        <div>                  
            <input placeholder="name" class="field__input" id="name" name="" required/>                                   
            <input placeholder="last name" class="field__input" id="last_name" name="" required/>
            <button id="step1Next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </output>

    <label for="2" class="pasos">Step 2</label>
    <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="2" value="2">
    <output>
        <div>
            <input placeholder="phone" class="field__input" id="phone" name="" required/>
            <button id="step2Next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </output>

    <label for="3" class="pasos">Step 3</label>
    <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="3" value="3">
    <output>
        <div>
            <input placeholder="address" class="field__input" id="address" name="" required/>
            <button id="step3Next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </output>
</fieldset>
```